# Unbroken loops loops

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop

Hi I have this problem that I can not solve.
I am a Prolog rookie and I've seen a ton of these family tree examples but none seem to address my problem.

Say I have

```
son(X, Y) :-
   \+daughter(X, Y),
   father(Y, X).

father(Y, X) :-
   male(X),
   son(X, Y).
```

and I call one of them, it will go back and forth between the conditions because each one would satisfy the one before, therefore resulting in a local stack error.

Most seem to recommend removing one of the definitions, but I need to answer father and son queries. Please, help, this seems so simple, but I just can not figure it out. How can I break after looping once?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

1) you could use a wrapper predicate:

```
father(Y,X):-
   male(X),
   son_data(X,Y).

son(X,Y):-
   son_data(X,Y).
son(X,Y):-
   \+daughter(X, Y), 
    father(Y, X).
```

your database should look like

```
son_data(mike,steph).
....
father(nick,john).
....
```

(no son/2 entries)

2) use a prolog version that supports [tabling](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Prolog#Tabling) (such as XSB) (or implement it; not such a good idea ofc)